# Ajax not working in the portlet configuration jsp page (liferay 6.2)

Tags: ajax, liferay, portlet

Working on a **MVCPortlet (Liferay 6.2)**.

Is there any reason why this ajax call works on a regular jsp of my portlet, but does not work on the config page of the portlet (the jsp that opens when you click top right corner and then configuration and option).

In this case, the `portletURL` is correctly displayed (alert), the JS returns success but the controller never received the client request.

Here's the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: portletURL,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: false,
    data: {
        test: test
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success ajax');
    },
    error: function(http, message, exc) {
        alert('error ajax');
    }
});
```

Again, this code works perfectly an another jsp.

Does this ring a bell to anybody?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. Tried both `liferay-portlet:resourceURL portletConfiguration="true"` and `portlet:resourceURL`, also with manual parsing and modifying the url before sending. The resource serving method (whether implementation of the `serveResource`, or completely new method using either Spring MVC or Liferay MVC (implementation class of `MVCPortlet`)), none worked in configuration mode.

The solution for me was to avoid resource serving at all and instead choose action phase (p_p_lifecycle=1). It is completely doable in AJAX, just had to override `processAction` method in my `DefaultConfigurationAction` implementation class.

Hope this saves someone the countless hours I spent with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Liferay 7.0.x and I found a working solution which could be applied to 6.2 but I have not an instance for test.

You have to generate the resource url with java code. As an example:

```
LiferayPortletURL resourceURL = (LiferayPortletURL) renderResponse.createResourceURL();
resourceURL.setPortletId(ParamUtil.getString(request, "portletResource"));
resourceURL.setResourceID("yourId");
```

Then use the `resourceURL.toString()` to generate the URL. The serverResource has to be implemented in the portlet class.